# How to handle if sum of integer array exceeds int max value(2147483647) using Arrays Stream?

Tags: arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have an integer array and want to sum all it's elements. It's working fine as far as sum is less than or equal to int max value(2147483647) but it's failing as soon as sum exceeds int max value. Below is the example-:

```
int [] iArr = new int[]{2147483646 , 1 , 1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(iArr).sum());
```

> Result-: -2147483648

As we can see above result is incorrect. I know that it can be resolved by using long array instead if int array as below.

```
long [] iArr = new long[]{2147483646 , 1 , 1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(iArr).sum());
```

> Result-: 2147483648

But I don't want to use long array because I know that maximum size limit of elements of array is with in int max value(2147483647). Hence I don't want to waste memory. Is there any other way to sum of integer array which(sum of elements of array) exceeds int max value(2147483647) using Array Stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need a `long[]` array, just to process the values as `long`s. The solution is as easy as one can imagine:

```
int[] iArr = new int[]{2147483646 , 1 , 1};
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(iArr).asLongStream().sum());
```

It’s unlikely to ever exceed the `long` range, as even if all elements are as big as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you would need 4294967298 stream elements to reach `Long.MAX_VALUE`. But if you have such a large stream and lots of time, or when a `LongStream` is your starting point, you can resort to `BigInteger` as follows:

```
long[] lArr={ Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE, 42 };
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(lArr).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
                         .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add));
```

note that this also works for `IntStream`s, as the promotion from `int` to `long` happens automatically when calling `BigInteger.valueOf(long)`, but as said above, this is rarely needed.

Answer (score 3):

This questions has already been answered but I found one more way to accomplish above task optimally. That's why I thought to share that with execution time statistics. **asLongStream** method of stream works optimally to convert integer stream to long.

```
int[] iArr = new int[10000000];
Arrays.fill(iArr , 3132);   

long iStart = System.nanoTime();
long  lSum1 = Arrays.stream(iArr).mapToLong(Long::valueOf).sum();
long iEnd = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("Sum-: " + lSum1);
System.out.println("Time in nanoseconds-: " + (iEnd - iStart) + "ns using \"mapToLong\"\n");

long iStart1 = System.nanoTime();
long lSum2 = Arrays.stream(iArr).asLongStream().sum();
long iEnd1 = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("Sum-: " + lSum2);
System.out.println("Time in nanoseconds-: " + (iEnd1 - iStart1) + "ns using \"asLongStream\"\n");

long iStart2 = System.nanoTime();
long lSum3 = Arrays.stream(iArr).boxed().collect(Collectors.summingLong(Integer::longValue));
long iEnd2 = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("Sum-: " + lSum3);
System.out.println("Time in nanoseconds-: " + (iEnd2 - iStart2) + "ns using \"Collectors\"\n");
```

> Output-:

Sum-: 31320000000
Time in nanoseconds-: 230369419ns using "mapToLong"

Sum-: 31320000000
Time in nanoseconds-: 109999469ns using "asLongStream"

Sum-: 31320000000
Time in nanoseconds-: 188769476ns using "Collectors"

Comment: Since the canonical solution `.asLongStream()` hadn’t been mentioned so far, it’s a pity that you’ve hidden it somewhere within a benchmark. I’ve seen it only after posting my answer. Anyway, it deserves my +1… Note that you are measuring the costs of printing the result, which shouldn’t be underestimated. And you should run the code within a loop multiple times to distinguish between initialization cost and actual calculation. Also `System.nanoTime()` is the preferred way to measure *elapsed time* as it is independent of the “wall clock” time, hence immune to NTP updates, leap seconds, etc.

Comment: @Holger , I have updated `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` to measure elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

If a long is big enough to hold the result then you could use a collector to sum the values to longs:

```
Arrays.stream(is).boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.summingLong(Integer::longValue));
```

If you need bigger than a long you may need to use a BigInteger, something like this:

```
Arrays.stream(is).boxed()
      .map(Integer::longValue)
      .collect(Collectors
      .reducing(new BigInteger("0"), BigInteger::valueOf, (b1, b2) -> b1.add(b2)));
```

Comment: `.boxed().map(Integer::longValue)` has an unnecessay intermediate boxed `Integer` step. You can just use `.mapToObj(Long::valueOf)`. Also you can use the constant `BigInteger.ZERO` instead of `new BigInteger("0")` and `(b1, b2) -> b1.add(b2)` is replaceable by `BigInteger::add`. But even then, this is [still way too complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40783926/2711488). Summing as `long` doesn’t require boxing at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the return type of sum matches the type of the stream. If you map it to a stream of Longs first then the sum can be returned properly.

```
int [] iArr = new int[]{2147483646 , 1 , 1};
Long sum = Arrays.stream(iArr)
        .mapToLong(Long::valueOf)
        .sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: `.mapToLong(…)` is handy when you want to calculate a `long` based on the `int` value, but for a simple type promotion, you can just use [`IntStream.asLongStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#asLongStream--). Also, there is no reason to box the `long` value into a `Long` object afterwards.

Comment: awesome! yep that is much better :)